# The schwa in [meɪkəθ] for *maketh* in KJV English

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, pronunciation, history

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English#Phonology) Wiki article seems to suggest that words like *makes* had lost their final syllable schwa in normal speech already by Chaucer's time (*palmeres* > *palmers* is the example they give). The rule, as formulated, would also apply to the form *maketh*: here also the schwa is only surrounded by single consonants on each side. Does this mean it was [makθ] rather than [makəθ] by Late Middle English?

Another reason to think that this schwa was lost would be the evidence of English dialects that preserved the -(e)th ending: cf. *wearth* (not *wear*e*th*) in the third line of the Yola "Maiden of Rosslare" poem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_and_Bargy_dialect#Examples).

Is it reasonable, then, to say that this schwa was no longer pronounced by King James's time?

*Maketh* is almost universally pronounced [meɪkəθ] and not *[meɪkθ] in litugrical KJV reading today, so if I'm right, this sound had to reappear at some point. XVII-century evidence like Hodges' *Special Help to Orthography* also suggests also that the -eth spelling was originally ignored, with people freely pronouncing -eth as [z] or [s]. Would the introduction of the spelling-pronuncation [əθ], then, be a suitable explanation for the schwa?

Comment: Surely quite a lot of aspects of the KJV are (deliberately) anachronistic?

Comment: Thanks @Draconis; the KJV is deliberately archaizing, that's for sure; what I meant though had more to do with the pronunciation of KJ English rather than KJ English itself. I tried to clarify that in the new question heading.

Comment: 1. How specific is the case you're arguing about how *-eth* was pronounced: more broadly that it was a separate syllable (no claim about its vowel) or more specifically that it was "[əθ]"? If the latter, what is the evidence for [ə]? 2. One factor licensing *wearth* is that rhotic English phonology allows syllable-final [ɹθ] -- perhaps some speakers used [θ] where no vowel is needed, but pronounced a vowel where needed?